# PhpStorm and git: how hide files not commited during checkout?

Tags: git, github, version-control, phpstorm

I'm using PHPStorm 2018.3.4.

My current git work method is the following:

- master: in-production branch, tagged
- development: branch from which I check out a `feature-somefeature` branch and where I merge the feature after all tests went OK.

So, for example, my work is

```
git checkout -b feature-adduser
[...] hard work with TDD
git add . && git commit -m "Add feature Adduser"
git push --set-upstream origin feature-adduser
```

On GitHub (because I have Travis and scrutinizer and codecov perform their auto checks) I merge the `feature-adduser` branch into developing. After merging, in local...

```
git checkout development
git pull --no-ff
git checkout -b feature-newfeature
[...] hard work
git add . && git commit -m "Implements new feature"
```

And so on.

In reality, using PHPStorm I right-click on files and click on "commit" directly, after that in terminal I launch the `git push[...]` command.

Now, I want to learn a can-be-possible scenario.

I'm in `feature-addfeature` branch (only on local, at the moment).
I edited `README.md` and **added** `IPTest.php` under Tests.

My boss calls me and I need to place a hotfix.

In theory, I would

```
git checkout development
git pull --no-ff
git checkout -b hotfix-cannotlogin
[...]hard work
git push --set-upstream origin hotfix-cannotlogin
```

and merge with GitHub.

The issue that I have, I did stage the modified/added files under `feature-addfeature` (via `VCS > Git > Stage files`) or via `git add .`, but, when I switch branch from `feature-addfeature` to `develop`, I have visible the new files and the edited file. Is it normal? Is there a mode to hide them? Am I wrong with the use of stage?

Sorry for long explanations.

Comment: What I usually do is use `git stash` to store my current changes, then create new branch do the hotfix, push, etc. Then I return to the branch where I was working and use `git pop` to restore the changes (I also use gitkraken, it gives a nice visualization of the branches and where is which stash).